# How to add a separate marker(an arrow) under a line

Tags: highcharts

I am new to [highcharts](https://www.highcharts.com/).  I have been trying to figure out how to add a marker such as an up arrow under a specific part of a line but I have not been able to find any example or document. what I found was on how to change the marker for each point of the same line. I would appreciate it greatly if someone could help me in the right direction.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `annotations.shapes`, for example:

```
    annotations: [{
        shapes: [{
            type: 'path',
            points: [...],
            markerEnd: 'arrow'
        }]
    }]
```

---

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/2L4to9q8/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highstock/annotations.shapes